# Calling exe through webservice - not display in front end

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.Net. I am working on a project where I have to Start another applcation from web service.

I am able to start the new application(Eq.Notepad) from form of my project. But If I try to start the new applciation from web service then The application is running in processes. I am able to see the application in Task manager processes. I am not able to see the application in front end.

I have tried ProcessStart, PSExecute , bat files running and their all parameters but nothing happened.

I am sure I am missing something but I dont know what exactly it is. 
Can Any one help me out of this? I would be thank to them

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to run applications from a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things:

- Windows Services run in a different desktop than the .NET process on modern (post XP) Windows versions. They have no access to the user interface (desktop) that another logged in user does. (Windows Vista and higher don't support services that interact with the desktop any longer as part of new security efforts and UAC.)
- Web apps should NOT be attempting to run executables on the local machine that give direct access to that machine from the web. If you feel the need to be doing this, you're doing something wrong and need to think harder about your design.